# Highcharts load data with ajax to populate the tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I understand how to load date in to the chart.
But now I wanna populate the tooltip with extra data.

This example works. It get the data.
The problem is the tooltip. When the tooltip is showed it will show it self before the Ajax call.
So you never will see the output of the Ajax call.

I thought I put a div id="test2" in it , when Ajax is done with it fill the div with data.
Highcharts doesn't display the div , it shows a span without a id.

The idea is: You have a chart with days and counts on them. If you hover on one of the points you get to see all the points that there where on that day...

How do I dynamic add extra data to the tooltip?

```
json data:
{"dagen":{"dagen":["2014-09-19 09:44:15","2014-09-19 22:35:06"],"aantal":["09:44","10:35"]}}



tooltip: {

    formatter: function() {
            var d ='<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
            this.y +'<br/><br /><div id="test2">ddd</div>';

               console.log('a');
             jQuery.getJSON("getdata.php?dateParam="+this.x, function(json)
                {
                        console.log('c');
                        var timearray = [];
                                        jQuery.each(json.dagen.dagen, function(i,times){
                                            timearray += times;
                                        });

                        console.log(timearray);

                        b = timearray;
                        //jQuery('#test2').html(timearray);
                });


                    console.log('b');
                    return d;


    }
},


console out put:
a
b
c
2014-09-19 09:44:152014-09-19 22:35:06
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three solutions:

1.) Forget the AJAX call.  You just cache all the "tooltip" data in memory on page load and load it using the formatter function.

2.) You make the AJAX call in the formatter synchronous.  This will *stall* the tooltip from popping up (and it will be "jerky"):

```
 formatter: function() {
    var rV = null;
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'ajax.json',
      async: false, // this will stall the tooltip
      success: function(ajax){
        rV = ajax.someProperty;
      }
    });
    return rV;
 }
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6nybzpa5efjcpqsUUFlR?p=preview).

3.) You keep the ajax async, display `Loading` in the tooltip, and then manipulate the tooltip after the ajax call completes.  Be careful with this, you'll have a race condition on the ajax call and it will be possible to have the *wrong* data retreived for a tooltip.

```
 formatter: function() {
    $.getJSON('ajax.json', function(ajax){
        var tt = Highcharts.charts[0].tooltip;
        var label = tt.label.element.lastChild; // find contents of tooltip
        $(label).text(ajax.someProperty);
    });
    return "...Loading...";
  }
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XkuseNgYXx8pJHrpdnzF?p=preview).

Comment: thx,  solution 2 and 3 aren't working if i move my mouse over a point and move to other point and back again. both give the wrong solution... about 1 i have to think about that one..

Comment: @Janis, yes, that's why I mentioned the possible "race conditions".  Since this is all async, you'll need to manage the calls.  Here's a little more robust implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/XkuseNgYXx8pJHrpdnzF?p=preview

Comment: the last update from you did do the job.. thats why market as solved

Answer (score 0):

Mark give me the right solution thats why I market it..

If you wanna show html in the tooltip at this

```
    useHTML: true,
```

This is the solution for me. I use dataFormat now because i switch to utc time stamp

```
tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                var msg ="<span>"+Highcharts.dateFormat('%A , %d %b', this.x)+'</span><br/>';
                msg = msg +"<b> Totaal: </b>" + this.y +'<br/><br />';
                msg = msg +'<table><body >';
                var msgEnd= '</body></table>';


                       console.log('a');
                     jQuery.getJSON("getdatachar.php?datedetailParam="+Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.x), function(json)
                        {
                                console.log('c');
                                var timearray = "";
                                jQuery.each(json.dagen.dagen, function(i,times){
                                    timearray = timearray + '<tr><td>'+times+ '</td></tr>';
                                });
                                console.log(timearray);

                                chart.tooltip.label.textSetter(msg+timeArray+msgEnd);
                        });


                            console.log('b');

                    return "Loading..";


            }
        }
```